# 'Sorry, that page does not exist.' code 34 for lists/statuses in Twitter API

Tags: node.js, twitter

What i think that i am doing right. but it constantly giving me error for the call. Do i have to setup a dev enviroment for lists/statuses in twitter settings or there is anything else need to be done in settings page.

Error

```
[ { code: 34, message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist.' } ]
```

The Code

```
var Twitter = require("twitter");

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: "", //Removed it
  consumer_secret: "",
  access_token_key: "",
  access_token_secret: "",
});
  var params = {
  list_id: some_id, // Removed it
  include_rts: false,
  exclude_replies: true,
};

client
  .get("lists/statuses", params)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

It works for [lists/list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-list) but it doesn't work for [lists/statuses](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-statuses)...

Comment: Are you certain you're using a valid list ID? Since you're using JavaScript, have you used the `_str` ID value?

Comment: @AndyPiper Yes! I have tried with both `id` and `id_str`. Different thing is that with `lists/statuses` `[ { code: 34, message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist.' } ]` _code_ appears first but with wrong endpoint e.g `lists/statusesss` it shows error like `[ { message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34 } ]`  in which _code_ appears second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `exclude_replies` in param option.
You should do

```
var params = {
  list_id: some_id, // Removed it
  include_rts: false,
};
```

This will work...